# EML files in a library are opened in the browser, I would like to open them in Outlook?

Tags: outlook, email-enabled-library

I am using SP2010. I have enabled mailing to a library (email enabled library). The received emails are saved as .eml files. When I click on the .eml file the browser open this file. But I don't have the outlook functionality like "answer, forward, forward all etc.".

I would like to open the .eml files in outlook. Is this possible?

I am using :

Win 7

Outlook 2010

IE 11

ps. in firefox it is working fine. In chrome it downloads the file when I click on the .eml file. After it is downloaded I can open it, and it wil be opened in Outlook. But I would like to make it working in IE :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to PowerShell, try this:

First check to see if eml is an permitted Mime Type.  Look for `message/rfc822`

```
$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication("http://yourwebappurl")
$webApp.AllowedInlineDownloadedMimeTypes
```

If it is in that list, remove it

```
$webApp.AllowedInlineDownloadedMimeTypes.Remove("message/rfc822")
$webApp.Update()
```

[Here's a lengthy explanation of browser handling of Mime Types](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/8073.sharepoint-browser-file-handling-deep-dive.aspx).